# The terminal process failed to launch Path to shell executable "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" does not exist

Tags: vscode

estoy teniendo un error extraño en vs code ayer trabaje y todo bien, hoy cuando lo abrí y trate de abrir el terminal me esta mostrando este error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" does not exist.
```

a que se debe este error? y como solucionarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007072/the-terminal-process-failed-to-launch-path-to-shell-executable-c-windows-syst) respuesta =)

Comment: allí no explican que archivo hay que modificar, no se entiende muy bien el post

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera expande tu comentario como una respuesta, indicando cómo cambiar el settings.json y tal.

Comment: la solucion fue la siguiente, reinicie la computadora y funciono xD